# log4net how best can I select just some logging in a class?

Tags: log4net

log4net does great on turning log levels on/off on a per class basis. But I have a case where I am implementing an interface and I have a ton of logging in this implementation. It's a 3rd party interface so I'm stuck having all this code, and hence all this logging, in a single class.

I've looked at creating helper classes for each of the areas of this implementation. But that actually makes things more messy. Partial classes work great for this, but again - still all one class.

Is there a good way to further specify which logging statements to log? The best I've come up with is an enum of the categories in the class and define each logging statement with the specific enum. And then use that enum in the if (log.IsDebugEnable && MyEnum == true)

Anything better?

**Update:** per the request below, actually showing all this would be so long/large that no one would read it. So here's a summation:

```
log.Debug("order placed");
// ...
log.Debug("new stock added");
// ...
log.Debug("price change");
// ...
log.Debug("order changed");
// ...
log.Debug("predicted price");
// ...
log.Debug("profit taken");
// ... the types of actions go on and on
```

All of the above is implementing a QCAlgorithm in QuantConnect. Basically there are times I want the details for orders logged. Other times I don't want those but do need to log the predicted price and actual price logging.

Comment: Please edit your question to include example source code to illustrate what interfaces/classes you have, which part is from a 3rd party library, which code you can and cannot change, how you have currently configured your logging, where/how you want to configure which logging call you want to log and what you have already tried.

Comment: You can setup multiple hierarchical loggers, which can have separated log levels. So you can use `logPrices.Debug("price change");` and such and configure them as you like. It is unclear what exactly the problem is.

Comment: @Progman I just did a Google search on this (thank you). Does this mean I would create say LogManager.GetLogger("myclass.A") & LogManager.GetLogger("myclass.B") in the same .cs file and use each ILog object as appropiate? TIA

Comment: It's up to you how you want to setup your logging hierarchy, nobody say you must use only one logger for each class via `GetLogger(Type)`. If you have a hierarchy which makes more sense semantically rather than namespace based, go for it. Unfortunately, as you see, this question is opinion-based and therefore off-topic.

Comment: @Progman If you want to write an answer that says to break it out into multiple ILog objects per source file, and saying that the structure of this can be done many different ways (therefore not rendering an opinion), I am happy to select that as the answer.